# Members in organic group module

Tags: organic-groups

I am using OG module for creating a group. Based on the group we made the functionality of adding a member, discussion based on the created group. I have a link with subscribing a member for my created group. I have doubt with how to show the added member in the front end group list. Please suggest me some ideas.

Thank you,
Sathish

Answer (score 0):

I think for that purpose, if I understood well, you need to use Views module with a user view you will be able to do create list or whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

Og module by default gives OG members view. Install [views](http://drupal.org/project/views) module and check for OG members view. Enable the block on all Group Landing pages. That should solve the problem!